# Any way to change the amount of dimming when using a UISheetPresentationController?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisheetpresentationcontroller

I've been working with `UISheetPresentationController` lately and am wondering if it's possible to change the amount of dimming when using a `UISheetPresentationController`. Looking at the documentation, it looks like I can remove the dimming with `largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier`, but I don't see anything related to making it darker.

Comment: I don't think there is a documented way to do this. You'd need to find the dimming view in the view hierarchy and add your own dimming view on top of it, or change it in some other way.

Comment: @Sweeper That's what I suspected. Also have to add functionality to remove the dimming view.

Comment: @matt Well the question says "when using a UISheetPresentationController". *Of course* you can do anything you like with your own `UIPresentationController`...

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way for now is to change the `alpha` of the presenting view controller in your bottom sheet being presented. Like so:

```
      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
          self.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 0.6
        }
      }
      override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
          self.presentingViewController?.view.alpha = 1
        }
      }
```

I hope later Apple will make this easier to do from the presenting side.